# Android: Reading Amplitude/Decibels for clapping detection using PercussionOnsetDetector from TarsosDSP

Tags: java, android, audio, detection, tarsosdsp

I am having trouble from getting the Amplitude/Decibel value while using PercussionOnsetDetector from TarsosDSP.  I have researched everywhere and found nothing from my searches that are relevant to my problem.  I have tried using MediaRecorder while using TarsosDSP but I am running with processing issues with that one. Is there a method or a way around to approach this?  Please let me know. Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Checks Permission
        checkPermission(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION);

        pitchText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pitch);
        counterText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.note);


        double threshold = 4.5;
        double sensitivity = 45;

        PercussionOnsetDetector mPercussionDetector = new PercussionOnsetDetector(22050, 1024,
                new OnsetHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void handleOnset(double time, double salience) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                counterText.setText("Counter: " + counter++);

                            }
                        });
                    }
                }, sensitivity, threshold);

        dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(mPercussionDetector);
        new Thread(dispatcher,"Audio Dispatcher").start();


    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "getting the Amplitude/Decibel value"? Are you trying to determine the appropriate values for `threshold/sensitivity`, from your previous question?

Comment: I just want to get the Amplitude reading from when I detect the clapping sound

Comment: I still couldn't figure this out.

Comment: What makes you think tarsos supports this? The `PercussionOnsetDetector` certainly doesn't. I looked at the source code. You'd have to re-write it.

Comment: I figured it wouldn't but my other attempt is utilizing the getMaxAmplitude() from MediaRecorder but it keeps getting me IllegalStateException or 0 on the getMaxAmplitude()

Comment: Yes, it doesn't surprise me that `MediaRecorder` wouldn't work that well if tarsos was already using the mic. You could implement your own `AudioProcessor` subclass, and add it using `addAudioProcessor()`. That'll give you a copy of the streaming audio, just like `PercussionOnsetDetector` gets. Then you'll have to figure out your own amplitude, from there.